# Deducing the existence of particular functions $\mathbb{N}\longrightarrow\mathbb{Q}$ in the context of Tom Leinster's "Rethinking Set Theory"

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory

This question concerns the set theory given by Tom Leinster in his paper "Rethinking Set Theory," available here: http://arxiv.org/abs/1212.6543

In this paper, axioms for set theory are given in the spirit of category theory, i.e., in the spirit of Lawvere's ETCS, but are written to be understandable at the undergraduate level. I am just an undergrad, and I do not have very much experience with set theory at all, so I apologize for my lack of background in this context.

My question is this: Leinster's Axiom 9 provides a system of natural numbers, from which one presumably may construct integers, rationals, etc. In my attempt to write out a quick construction of the real numbers as equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences, I am stuck on the following:

> Given a set of rational numbers $\{r_1,r_2,r_3,...\}$, do the axioms in this paper guarantee the existence of a function $f\in \mathbb{Q}^{\mathbb{N}}$ such that $f(1)=r_1,$ $f(2)=r_2,$ $f(3)=r_3,$ etc.?

Leinster's axiom 6 states that the collection of functions between two sets is again a set, but I can't seem to understand how to deduce the existence of such a function within this theory. Given a function $g:\mathbb{N}\longrightarrow\mathbb{Q}$, I understand that $g(n)=g\circ n$, where $n:\mathbb{1}\longrightarrow \mathbb{N}$ denotes the element $n$, and that this shows $g(n)$ is indeed an element of $\mathbb{Q}.$

Can someone help me understand this? Again I apologize for my lack of understanding, I am merely fascinated by this paper and have not had any education in the area of set theory.

Comment: What do you mean by a "set" of rational numbers?

Comment: I think it would be the collection of equivalence classes of certain pairs of integers. Given a pair $(x,y)$ of integers, I think I can show there exists a function $f:\mathbb{1}+\mathbb{1}\longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(a)=x$ and $f(b)=y$, where $a,b$ are the distinct elements of $\mathbb{1}+\mathbb{1}$, by the definition of a disjoint union in this context (coproduct). Existence of coproducts in not given as an axiom here but is implied by them.

Comment: In the context of my question, I think any set would do for $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: What I mean is, what does the notation $\{r_1,r_2,r_3,\dots\}$ mean?  This notation is not part of the formal language of Leinster's axioms, so you need to define it somehow.

Comment: I see, by that I just mean a collection of functions $r_{i}:\mathbb{1}\longrightarrow \mathbb{Q}$. I believe this collection forms a subset of the set $\mathbb{Q}^{\mathbb{1}}$ by Axiom 6.

Comment: But what is a "collection"?

Comment: How about this: given a function $r:\mathbb{1}\longrightarrow \mathbb{Q}$, do the axioms imply the existence of a function $f:\mathbb{N}\longrightarrow\mathbb{Q}$ such that $f(n)=r$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Sure, just compose $r$ with the unique function $\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{1}$ given by Axiom 2.

Comment: That makes sense. Now, given $r,s:\mathbb{1}\longrightarrow \mathbb{Q}$, do the axioms imply the existence of a function $f:\mathbb{N}\longrightarrow\mathbb{Q}$ such that $f(0)=r$ and $f(n)=s$ otherwise?

Comment: Yes, but this is fairly difficult to prove.

Comment: I see. I guess that is what was meant by my question. Do you know of anywhere that I could find such a proof or something similar? It seems that if I could show that there exists a function $g:\mathbb{Q}\longrightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ such that $g(r_1)=r_2$, $g(r_2)=r_3$, etc., then I could apply the natural number axiom to find the function I seek.

Comment: You're definitely asking the wrong question here, but I'm afraid I don't have the time or energy to explain in more detail right now.

Comment: Do you have the time and energy to clarify what you mean by "asking the wrong question?" As I said, I do not have experience with set theory, and I don't think my original question is nonsensical. I am not sure what you are getting out of trying to make me feel like I don't deserve an answer because I don't have a good feel for the details of this topic. I feel you understand what is meant by my question, even if I may not have phrased it in a fully rigorous way.

Comment: I guess Eric wanted to head you for restating your condition about '*given $r_1,r_2,\dots$ rational numbers*' in a form that is rigorously expressible in this theory. And, I guess, what you will find is that this '$r_1,r_2,\dots$' is *a priori* given by a function $\Bbb N\to\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I'm not meaning to be unhelpful, it's just that it would take a rather long answer to explain exactly the right way to think about what's going on here.  The basic problem is that you have an intuitive notion of what an "infinite sequence of rational numbers" is, but it is difficult to make this mathematically precise.  In any case, it is a separate philosophical question whether your set theory needs to be able to represent every infinite sequence you can imagine; it might be able to construct a perfectly good system of "real numbers" nevertheless.

Comment: By the way, these issues have nothing to do with Leinster's axioms in particular--they would arise in exactly the same way for ZFC, for instance.  In order to formulate a theorem of the form "for all sequences of rational numbers, there is a function $\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{Q}$", you have to first define "sequence of rational numbers" in the language of your theory.

Comment: Thank you both Berci and Eric, I'd like to apologize for my frustration earlier. I think I am beginning to understand my misunderstanding due to intuitive assumptions--I am sure one of the most common difficulties encountered when learning these kinds of maths for the first time. Thank you both for your time in helping me to see where I went wrong.